# Incorrect syntax near '+'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working on c# (viusul studio) as a beginner. I am trying to create a database application that contains many tables and forms. My problem is... insert and update queries are working fine on one form and one table of the database. But when I apply the same query on another form for another table, it does'nt work.

I used the following syntax for other form of my project and it worked.

```
String strSQL1 = "UPDATE  Personal_Info SET Roll_No=Roll_No, Std_Name=@Std_Name, F_Name=@F_Name,Gender=@Gender,Domicile=@Domicile WHERE Roll_No=@Roll_No";
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(strSQL1, con);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Roll_No", Roll_No);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Std_Name", Std_Name);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@F_Name", F_Name);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Gender);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Domicile", Domicile);
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is what I am trying on the other form. It gives me two exceptions
1)Incorrect syntax near '+'.

2)Incorrect syntax near '('.

```
String strSQL1 = "UPDATE Sem_1 SET (Roll_No=@Roll_No,DLD=@dld,C++=@cpp,OS=@os,DBMS=@dbms,BC=@bs,Isl=@isl,Obm=@obm,SGPA=@semgpa,Per=@per,Grade=@grade) WHERE Roll_No=@Roll_No";
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(strSQL1,con);
//Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Roll_No",Roll_No);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DLD",dld);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C++",cpp);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OS",os);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DBMS",dbms);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BC",bc);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Isl",isl);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Obm",obm);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SGPA",semgpa);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Per",per);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grade",grade);
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Kindly help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Pleas reformat your question. I don't understand why I can't edit your question by the way. It gives `The post could not be loaded` error..

Comment: Also, I don't know if this falls under edit, but please retag to c# and SQL, or with the specific SQL server you are using.

Answer (score 3):

If you *format out* your code, you'll see that you're tring to use **C++** as
identifator in the SQL query which is *forbidden*. You should either 
*rename* the field *C++* into something like *Cpp* in the *Sem_1* table, or use quotations in the query: "C++" (since you use *MS SQL* you may also put the name into *brackets*: [C++])

```
String strSQL1 = 
  "UPDATE Sem_1 
      SET (Roll_No=@Roll_No,
           DLD=@dld,
           C++=@cpp, -- <- You can't use + in SQL fields lake that; if you insist, do it like \"C++\"
           OS=@os,
           DBMS=@dbms,
           BC=@bs,
           Isl=@isl,
           Obm=@obm,
           SGPA=@semgpa,
           Per=@per,
           Grade=@grade) 
    WHERE Roll_No=@Roll_No";
```

Comment: Why not simply use `[C++]` wouldn't that work for SQL?

Comment: @ Nunners: Thank you! I've not recognized at the first glance, that MS SQL is used; quotations will do at any Sql server

Answer (score 3):

As selman mentioned above, `C++=@cpp` in your SQL text is an issue.

Enclose your column names in square brackets such as `[C++]=@cpp` - this will avoid any ambiguity with Sql keywords and such.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in C++=@cpp

I guess this should be something like [C++]=@cpp, or the ++ is a typo? And in your params:

```
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C++",cpp); 
->
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpp", cpp);
```

And you should remove the: '(' and ')' from your update statement to fix the "Incorrect syntax near '('.".

Comment: Thanks.Now with this correction one of the error (Incorrect syntax near '+'.) is fixed. But there is still another exception ( Incorrect syntax near '('. ). So what to do with this?

Comment: The second error is fixed too. Now my code is asking me to declare a scalar variable @semgpa which is declared as double in same mathod. And in the database this field is created as real. So how could i fix tis problem?

Comment: A real is a Single in c#, so try to convert the double to a Single:
   Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SGPA",Convert.ToSingle(semgpa));

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is here:

```
C++=@cpp,
```

I don't know what is your column name but you should fix this, you are trying to add a value `@C++` but there is no `@C++` in command text, you are using it as a Column name

```
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C++",cpp);
```

Update: You should remov parentheses from your command string

```
UPDATE Sem_1 SET ( ... )
```

It should be:

```
UPDATE Sem_1 SET ...
```

Comment: Thanks.Now with this correction one of the error (Incorrect syntax near '+'.) is fixed. But there is still another exception ( Incorrect syntax near '('. ). So what to do with this?

Comment: remove parentheses from your command string "UPDATE Sem_1 SET `(`... `)`"

Answer (score 0):

try removing the parenthesis enclosing your values in SET...

Comment: Fixed the error with this correction. Thanks for your help. Now my code is asking me to declare a scalar variable @semgpa which is declared as double in same method. And in the database this field is created as real. So how could i fix this problem?